# usbvgadock2 startech ubuntu driver

Tags: drivers

How do I get the USBVGADOCK2 to work with my Toshiba Ubuntu Laptop?

Is there a driver available - it says on web that it is compatible although it keeps referring to Windows OS.

Comment: What are your research results so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse us as this is our first post (my wife and I).

We have two of these devices and can get them working with USB, sound and internet but not VGA. We are both running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have Googled loads and found a suggestion to edit the xorg.conf file but I didn't have any joy with that. I made the changes but the video still doesn't work on the device. The link I found that I tried is here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1398488.

The first page of answers on Google are either links to this question or relate to the usb2vga box which is a different item. It sees that these are not very popular.

Any pointers about where to look would be helpful as I am not expecting an answer on a plate but just some idea of where to go.

Many thanks
Mike (and Sue)

Comment: Also carried out the instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB2VGA but ended up with a black screen and struggled to get out of it.